# Cursor logic error

Tags: sql-server

i wrote this SP to store data from two tables in which the second table contain sectionID
i want to distribute the student into their section

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[StudentDistribution] -- '6,7,8,9,10','1,2',1,1   
(
@pUserID varchar(8000),
@pSectionID varchar(8000),
@pClassID int,
@pModifiedBy int
)
as




DECLARE @Cntr int   
set @Cntr = (select count(*) from split(@pUserID,','))
select sum(Capacity) from SectionsClasses where ClassID=@pClassID and SectionID in (select vItem from split(@pSectionID,','))

DECLARE FetchStudent Cursor for
select vItem from split(@pUserID,',')

DECLARE @vUserID  int
DECLARE @vSecID int
DECLARE @vOut_Status int
DECLARE @vInner_Status int

        Open FetchStudent
        Fetch NEXT From FetchStudent into @vUserID
        set @vOut_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS 
        WHILE @vOut_Status = 0 

            begin 
            DECLARE FetchSection Cursor for
            select vItem from split(@pSectionID,',')

                OPEN FetchSection
                    Fetch NEXT From FetchSection into @vSecID
                    set @vInner_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS
                    WHILE @vInner_Status = 0 
                    begin

                    print(@vUserID)
                    print(@vSecID)


                    --IF @cntr <= 0
                    --  break
                    --else
                    --  set @Cntr=@Cntr-1



                    Fetch NEXT From FetchStudent into @vUserID
                    set @vOut_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS

                    Fetch NEXT From FetchSection into @vSecID
                    set @vInner_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS




                    END
                    Close FetchSection
                    Deallocate FetchSection

            --IF @cntr <= 0
            --          break
            --      else
            --          set @Cntr=@Cntr-1
            Fetch NEXT From FetchStudent into @vUserID

            END
    Close FetchStudent
    Deallocate FetchStudent
```

i need to get this result

```
6  1
7  2
8  1
9  2
10 1
```

but what i got is

```
6  1
7  2
9  1
10 2
```

can anyone figure out where is the problem ??

Comment: I'll admit, I'm terrible at reading CURSORs because I never write them.  I think what you're trying to do is given a table with a SectionID and then a list of students in a comma seperated list, explode the list of students into so they each feature on a row?  Please confirm what you are trying to achieve generally as opposed to what the CURSOR is trying to do, and please add your data structure and some sample data to help us help you.

Comment: i have list of student in a comma separated list and also list of Sections in a comma separated list, and i used split function which return table contain vItem attribute which is the list but in each row what i want to do is to distribute the section table which came from split into student table

Comment: Why can't you use a set-based approach?

Comment: what is set-based @FreshPrinceOfSO ???

Comment: [Understanding “Set based” and “Procedural” approaches in SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches)

Comment: Please set up a SQL Fiddle showing the problem. There must be something I'm missing...

Comment: Show us the definition of the `split` function so we can see how it works and what it returns.

Comment: the function split when see comma
and return 
table_name(ID,vItem)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[StudentDistribution] --'6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13','1',3,1   
(
@pUserID varchar(8000),
@pSectionID varchar(8000),
@pClassID int,
@pModifiedBy int    
)
as



DECLARE @vCntr int  
DECLARE @vCapacity int 

set @vCntr = (select count(*) from split(@pUserID ,','))
select  @vCapacity = sum(Capacity) from SectionsClasses where ClassID=@pClassID and SectionID in (select vItem from split(@pSectionID,','))

    if @vCntr >  @vCapacity
    BEGIN
        print('Operation cannot complete; the number of student exceeds capacity')
            Return
    END

DECLARE FetchStudent Cursor  SCROLL for
select vItem from split(@pUserID,',')

DECLARE @vUserID  int
DECLARE @vSecID int
DECLARE @vOut_Status int
DECLARE @vInner_Status int

        Open FetchStudent
        Fetch NEXT From FetchStudent into @vUserID
        set @vOut_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS 
        WHILE (@vOut_Status = 0 )

            begin 
            DECLARE FetchSection Cursor  SCROLL for
            select vItem from split(@pSectionID,',')

                OPEN FetchSection
                    Fetch NEXT From FetchSection into @vSecID
                    set @vInner_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS
                    WHILE (@vInner_Status = 0 )
                    BEGIN

                    print(@vUserID)
                    print(@vSecID)


                    Fetch NEXT From FetchSection into @vSecID
                    set @vInner_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS
                    --IF @vInner_Status = -1
                    --      BREAK
                    Fetch NEXT From FetchStudent into @vUserID
                    set @vOut_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS 
                        IF @vOut_Status = -1
                            BREAK


                    END

                    Close FetchSection
                    Deallocate FetchSection



            IF @vInner_Status =-1
            Fetch PRIOR From FetchStudent into @vUserID

            Fetch NEXT From FetchStudent into @vUserID
            set @vOut_Status= @@FETCH_STATUS

            END
    Close FetchStudent
    Deallocate FetchStudent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to consider as an alternative to your cursor:

```
WITH sections AS (
  SELECT
    x.ID,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.ID)
  FROM dbo.split(@pSectionID, ',') AS f
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(f.vItem AS int)) AS x (ID)
),
users AS (
  SELECT
    x.ID,
    SectionRN = NTILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sections)) OVER (ORDER BY x.ID)
  FROM dbo.split(@pUserID, ',') AS f
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(f.vItem AS int)) AS x (ID)
)
SELECT
  UserID    = u.ID,
  SectionID = s.ID
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN sections AS s ON u.SectionRN = s.RN
;
```

For `@pUserID` as `'6,7,8,9,10'` and `pSectionID` as `'1,2'`, the above will return a result set like this:

```
UserID  SectionID
------  ---------
6       1
7       1
8       1
9       2
10      2
```

If you insist on the result like this:

```
UserID  SectionID
------  ---------
6       1
7       2
8       1
9       2
10      1
```

change the `SectionRN` calculation in `users` to this:

```
SectionRN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.ID) - 1) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sections) + 1
```

---

Useful reading:

- [Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

  - [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)
  - [NTILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)
- [WITH common_table_expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)